# Blazor Wasm - CascadingValue update from descending component

Tags: .net, blazor, telerik, blazor-webassembly

I want a global loading indicator on my application. I have already a component for that, LoadingIndicator.razor:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <TelerikLoaderContainer Visible="@( IsVisible )" Text="@Text" />
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {

    [Parameter]

    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }


    [Parameter]
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; } }
```

and somewhere in my component tree I try the following, childComponent.razor

```
[CascadingParameter]
protected LoadingContainer LoadingContainer { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    LoadingContainer.Text = "test";
    LoadingContainer.IsVisible = true;
}
```

according to the warning `BL0005` thats not allowed due to inconsistent Ui (possibly). But how could I show the loading indicator on my child components? I would not like to use inheritance because I want to be flexible whether and where I want to use it. The CascadingValue is applied at the `MainLayout` level so all components have it available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to trigger an update in the parent.

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <TelerikLoaderContainer Visible="@( IsVisible )" Text="@Text" />
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    //[Parameter] -- you can make these private fields now
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    //[Parameter] -- same
    public string Text { get; set; } 

    public void ShowLoader(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
        IsVisible = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    //LoadingContainer.Text = "test";
    //LoadingContainer.IsVisible = true;
    LoadingContainer.ShowLoader("test");
}
```